# How to draw a constant line between a series of CLLocationCoordinate in a MapView

Tags: swift, mapkit

I have got an Array of `CLLocationCoordinate`. I want to draw a constant line.This line will link each adjacent `CLLocationCoordinate` so when the `CLLocationCoordinates`‘ distance is very near the line will look like a curve.I wonder how to develop it?
I tried to use the MKPolyLine like this:

```
var polyline:MKPolyline=MKPolyline(coordinates: arrcoordinate, count: arrcoordinate.count);
```

but it didn't meet my desire. I also tried like the `MKGeodesicPolyline`,and it also did not meet my desire.

I just make this probem simple,so I make an array of CLLocationCoordinate like this:

```
var arrcoordinate:[CLLocationCoordinate2D]=[CLLocationCoordinate2D].init();
        arrcoordinate.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: 100, longitude: 39));
        arrcoordinate.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: 128, longitude: 33));
        arrcoordinate.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: 118, longitude: 55));
        arrcoordinate.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: 122, longitude: 57));
        print(arrcoordinate)
        var polyline:MKPolyline=MKPolyline.init(coordinates: &arrcoordinate, count: arrcoordinate.count);
        self.MapView.addOverlay(polyline);
```

and make the OverlayRender delegate like this:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if overlay is MKPolyline {
            var polylineRenderer=MKPolylineRenderer.init(overlay: overlay);
            polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.white;
            polylineRenderer.lineWidth=2
            return polylineRenderer
        }

        return MKOverlayRenderer.init();
    }
```

but there is no any line appears on the mapview,so I dont know why?

Comment: "but it didn't meet my desire" Explain. What did you get, and how does it differ from what you wanted?

Comment: what i need is a curve built with small lines,but what i get is a series of rectangles

Comment: So you're saying you have a series of points and you want a smooth curve that passes through them?

Comment: Not too smooth,but the points' distance is very small,so it will looks like a curve

Comment: well, in that case a sequence of straight lines _will_ look sufficiently like a curve. So why isn't that happening for you? Maybe it would help if you showed enough code to let us reproduce the issue.

Comment: I just make the probem simple ,I defined a simple array of CLLocationCoordinate,I have supplied the question above,please help me check

Comment: Are you the map view's delegate?

Comment: yes,i have set the detegate

Comment: Isn't the problem that your coordinates are nonsensical? There is no such thing as latitude 100, 128, and so on. Latitudes run from -90 to 90.

Comment: Also your polyline is going to be white, which could make it hard to see.

Comment: ok,I have solve the probem,it is the problem of range of the latitude and longitude

Comment: I rather think _I_ solved it, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me.

[image]

I had to change your code a little, because your coordinates are nonsensical. So my version of your code looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.map.delegate = self
        var arrcoordinate = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
        arrcoordinate.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 39))
        arrcoordinate.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 28, longitude: 33))
        arrcoordinate.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 18, longitude: 55))
        arrcoordinate.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 22, longitude: 57))
        let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &arrcoordinate, count: arrcoordinate.count)
        self.map.add(polyline)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if overlay is MKPolyline {
            let polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            polylineRenderer.strokeColor = .red
            polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 2
            return polylineRenderer
        }
        return MKOverlayRenderer()
    }
}
```